# Javascript notation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came upon a notation I'm not too familiar with and would like some direction to where to look.

the notation is `"selector event" : function() {}`

so for example

`".elementClass change" : function() {}`

Comment: It's just a key pointing to a function. It's not special. Is this in Backbone?

Comment: What libraries are you using?

Comment: Backbone.js uses something like this: http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents

Comment: It could be a simple conditional `condition ? true_expr : false_expr` syntax that gives you string if true, and an empty function otherwise.

Comment: Looks like Backbone.js to me, except that backbone syntax is "event selector": function(){}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This notation is for a `key-value` pair within an `object`. The specific example is for a function value belonging to a selector and event key. The function is then accessible using the key:

```
var obj = {
    ".elementClass change": function () {}
};
var func = obj[".elementClass change"];
```

Comment: Found the notation in javascriptmvc. Thanks for the explanation on key-value pairs in javascript. I'm sure jmvc is using it for the event listeners.

Comment: @WillHuang Yup it parses the key finds the elements that match the selector and attach event listeners for the event.